# CSS sidenav text not fading in on ngIf or sidenav opening

Tags: html, css, angular

I would like to show the text on the sidenav to fade in on opening and to fade out on closing. I dont like how the text just "pop" in when opening the sidenav.

I have this animations template here

```
export const animateText = trigger('animateText', [
  state('hide',
    style({
      'display': 'none',
      opacity: 0,
    })
  ),
  state('show',
    style({
      'display': 'block',
      opacity: 1,
    })
  ),
  transition('close => open', animate('1500s ease-in')),
  transition('open => close', animate('1500s ease-out')),
]);
```

Here is my html

```
<div class="sidenav_container"  [@onSideNavChange]="sideNavState ? 'open' : 'close'">
  <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="10px" style="height: 100%;">

    <div class="user_menu text-center">
      <mat-nav-list >
        <a mat-list-item >
          <img class="jim" src="https://a57.foxnews.com/media2.foxnews.com/BrightCove/694940094001/2018/06/21/931/524/694940094001_5800293009001_5800284148001-vs.jpg?ve=1&tl=1" alt="">
          <span [@animateText]="linkText ? 'show' : 'hide'">{{ page?.name }} </span>
        </a>
      </mat-nav-list>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    </div>

    <div>
      <header style="text-align:center; background-color:lightgray; color:royalblue;">Links</header>
      <mat-nav-list>
        <a mat-list-item *ngFor="let page of pages">
          <mat-icon style="padding-right:5px;">{{page?.icon}}</mat-icon>
          <span [@animateText]="linkText ? 'show' : 'hide'">{{ page?.name }} </span>
        </a>
      </mat-nav-list>
    </div>
  </div>

  <span class="spacer"></span>
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end end" style="padding: 0px 10px;">
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="onSinenavToggle()">
      <mat-icon *ngIf="sideNavState">arrow_left</mat-icon>
      <mat-icon *ngIf="!sideNavState">arrow_right</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the stackblitz showing what I mean. When you open the sidenav container the text just pops or appears. I want it to fade in

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9kjy2t?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fleft-menu%2Fleft-menu.component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you made a litte mistake with your transitions in your `animateText` animation:

```
transition('close => open', animate('1500s ease-in')),
transition('open => close', animate('1500s ease-out')),
```

should rather be:

```
transition('hide => show', animate('1500ms ease-in')),
transition('show => hide', animate('1500ms ease-out'))
```

In addition, it's not possible to create animations with the `display`property. You should rather use `max-width` or `transfrom: scale()`.

An example would be:

```
export const animateText = trigger('animateText', [
  state('hide',
    style({
      opacity: 0,
      'max-width': 0,
      transform: 'scale(.5)'
    })
  ),
  state('show',
    style({
      opacity: 1,
      'max-width': '200px',
      transform: 'scale(1)'
    })
  ),
  transition('hide => show', animate('250ms ease-in')),
  transition('show => hide', animate('250ms ease-out'))
]);
```

**EDIT:** You can also take a look at [keyframe animations](https://angular.io/api/animations/keyframes) for more complex animations. With keyframes it would be possible to use the `display: none` property.

```
 transition('show => hide', [
      animate(
        `500ms linear`,
        keyframes([
          style({ transform: 'scale(1)', opacity: 1, offset: 0 }),
          style({ transform: 'scale(.5)', opacity: 0, offset: .99 }),
          style({ transform: 'scale(.5)', opacity: 0, display: 'none', offset: 1 }),
        ])
      )
    ])
```

(`offset` indicates the animation progress)

The example above creates a fade-out animation and adds a `display: none` after the animation reached 100%.
Because the `display: none` is added at the end, it doesn't break the animation.

Comment: Simon thanks for this answer.  I notice that the "header" doesn't fade out it just disappears. Is there a way to get it to fade out like the rest of the text? if i remove the hidden property it just creates a blank space. *ngIf doesn't work either

Comment: I added an edit to the post on how you can "remove" an element after the animation. I hope this will help you.